# How to Hide selected item from a databounded combobox (Datagridviewcombobox)

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, ado.net, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a bounded combobox inside datagridview ( DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ) and
I want to hide selected item of that combobox in the next row of the grid

for example :

combo box values are,

```
[value 1 ]                   
[value 2 ]                       
[value 3 ]                     
[value 4 ]
```

ok. Just think there is 4 rows in my datagridviw, now when I select [value 1] from the combobox I dont want that value to the next combo beneath the first row (means I don't want that value to the next row combobox )

Is there any solution ?

Comment: I think that to accomplish what you want, you have to make it un-bound and add/delete items manually.

Comment: is ther any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

How about Using the Linq?

```
XXXX.where(x => x.value!=1).ToList()
```

Comment: any other way ? other than linq